Disable Alt+H in Intel graphics command center
I recently installed a new version of the Intel graphics driver on my Windows 10 machine. Previously, I used Alt+H as a custom keyboard shortcut in my text editor, but now when I press Alt+H in the editor nothing happens and instead there's a notification from Intel that says "Could not start Highlights - Selected audio device was not found"
So I went to Intel Graphics Command Center and looked on the "HotKeys" tab, but it says that my system hotkeys are turned off and even when turned on there's no Alt+H in the list.
How can I disable Alt+H in Intel so that I can keep using it as before?

How did you setup the shortcut in the text editor originally?

@Ramhound It was in a custom-set shortcut in Neovim

I’m voting to close this question because it has been resolved and does not need any more answers.

While Intel Graphics Command Center does not have an option to disable the Alt+H hotkey, Intel Arc Control does. I entered Arc Control, went to the Hotkeys tab, and from there disabled all hotkeys.

I don't have a system to test this on, but I believe the issue is caused by the Intel Arc Control which is installed by default as part of the driver update, unless you do a custom install and opt out. It assigns itself to certain keyboard shortcuts that cannot be configured or disabled.I found a Reddit thread complaining about this, which apparently claims this has become a particular headache for Blender users.
In terms of a solution: see if you can stop this process from running by default on startup, as I believe it isn't absolutely required for the drivers to work. Or perhaps rollback the driver update (if that's possible) and reapply with a customised install, as apparently there's an option to avoid installing the ARC Control extra.

Problem solved! I didn't think to look in Arc Control, I was only looking in Intel Graphics Command Center. I found that Arc Control DOES have a setting to disable hotkeys.

So I guess Intel must have updated Arc Control since that Reddit thread

@Wilson, the protocol is to tick the answer, when it helps you.

@RohitGupta is it? It certainly did help me and deserves the most credit, but it doesn't exactly solve the issue. That's why I added another answer.
